# Adding custom errors inside safecracker_submit_entry_end hook

Tags: safecracker

I'm doing some post-processing after a Safecracker form has been submitted.  During my post-processing if I want to encounter an error, I'd like to set one and have it show up as an error when the page reloads. I would assume you can do this somehow using the $safecracker object you have use of inside the hook, I'm just not sure how.

Any help or insight would be appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. First, you probably want to use `safecracker_submit_entry_start`. If you use `safecracker_submit_entry_end`, the entry will already be in the database, which presumably you want to avoid if your custom error conditions are met.

Setup your extension to use the `safecracker_submit_entry_start` hook (you can use [pkg.io](http://pkg.io) for a quick start), and have it call a method of the same name in your extension.

Then, pass the Safecracker object by reference so you can modify it in the parent context rather than locally.

```
function safecracker_submit_entry_start(&$safecracker)
{
    // do some stuff
    $safecracker['errors'][] = 'You didn't pass my special tests.';
}
```

That should be it.

Comment: Oops looks like I confirmed a little too soon, the actual code should be

`$safecracker->errors[] = "You didn't pass my special tests.";`

Comment: Ah, good catch Bryant.

Comment: Is there any documentation on how to set field errors as opposed to global errors?